# gitlabのwikiページの添付ファイルを削除する方法が見つからない

Tags: centos, gitlab

gitlab 8.2.0
を
Centos 6.5上に構築しています。

wiki ページで添付するのは[Attach a file]でできるのですが、
削除する方法がわかりません。

サーバ上にログインして確認すると
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads
という場所にどんどんたまり続けるようです。

一つの解決策として「気にしない」もありかと思いますが、
何か消す方法はありませんか？